# Promise seems to not resolve at all

Tags: angular, promise

I'm trying to write a typewriter effect in Angular but it seems like my promise is not correctly resolved in the component calling the `TypeWriter`:

```
export class TypeWriter {

    constructor(t, speed) {
        this.content = t.innerHTML;
        this.t = t;
        this.typeSpeed = speed;
        this.t.innerHTML = '';
    }

    private content: string;
    private cursorPosition = 0;
    private tag = '';
    private writingTag = false;
    private tagOpen = false;
    private typeSpeed = 50;
    private t;

    public type(): Promise<void> {
        return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
            if (this.cursorPosition >= this.content.length) {
                console.log('done typewriter');
                resolve();
            }

            if (this.content[this.cursorPosition]) {
               // Typewriting logic
            }

            if (++this.cursorPosition <= this.content.length) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    this.type();
                }, this.typeSpeed);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And in the component :

```
  initTypewriter() {
    const typewriter = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="typewriter"]');
    if (!typewriter.length || typewriter.length == 0) { return; }

    const typers: TypeWriter[] = [];
    typewriter.forEach(t => {
      typers.push(new TypeWriter(t, 50));
    });

    typers[0].type().then(() => { console.log('done tw0'); });
    typers[1].type().then(() => { console.log('done tw1'); });
  }
```

What I would like to achieve is to trigger the typewriter sequentially. I am aware of `reduce()` and know how to use it but here my problem is that the `type()` promise seems like it's never resolved. My console outputs :

```
done typewriter
done typewriter
```

But I never get the `done twX` to output in my console even if the console log just before the `resolve()` is displayed...

Am I missing something obvious here ?

Comment: Since you have wrapped more than one if statement in the promise, and only one if statement results in the promise being resolved, I don't think it will resolve in any case but the first (this.cursorPosition >= this.content.length)  Also you can include a rejection if you forsee a reason for the promise not to be 'settled'.

Comment: Well it makes sense since I want my promise to resolve only when it is done typing

Comment: Ah - I missed that.  Maybe you want to use Promise.all() - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Farasi78 is right. As written, the Promise will not be resolved unless the first of the `if()` conditions is met - and not if `this.type()` is called. Therefore only the last Promise of the recursion will settle. All others will remain pending. Try `this.type().then(resolve);`.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Yes, thanks for this. `this.type().then(resolve)` worked. But I got it working yesterday with `resolve(this.type())` and I don't really get the difference between these two statements...

Comment: The two expressions are synonymous in this case. My version works only because `.type()` returns Promise. Your version would work whether `type()` returns Promise or a value.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Thank you for the explanation, too bad I cannot mark a comment as an answer :)

Comment: @AntoineThiry, no worries. I hope you continue to enjoy writing JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to resolve your promise every time just you did in `this.cursorPosition >= this.content.length` condition

first of all wrap setTimeout with a promise.

```
const setTimeoutProm = (delay) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(),delay))
```

then change your `type()` method to ,

```
public type(): Promise<void> {
        return new Promise<void>((resolve) => {
            if (this.cursorPosition >= this.content.length) {
                console.log('done typewriter');
                resolve();
            }

            if (this.content[this.cursorPosition]) {
               // Typewriting logic
               // maybe resolve() 
            }

            if (++this.cursorPosition <= this.content.length) {
                setTimeoutProm(this.typeSpeed).then(() => { 
                   return this.type();
                }).catch(err => { })
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I get that I have to resolve every time, I actually made it work with replace the last `this.type()` in the timeout with `resolve(this.type())`.
I tried with your method but unfortunatly, my promise is still not resolved.